# Intuition of Influence Function and Score function: $E[IF(X)S_{\beta}(X; \theta_0)]$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, asymptotics, influence-function

### Question

I find a theorem regarding influence function and score function
\begin{align*}
E\left\{IF(Z) S_\beta\left(Z, \theta_0\right)\right\}&=1\\
E\left\{IF(Z) S_\eta^T\left(Z, \theta_0\right)\right\}&=0^{r}
\end{align*}
, where IF is the influence function. Also, $S_\beta$ is the score function regarding target parameter and $S_{\eta}$ is that of nuisance parameter.

What is the intuition of the theorem? A textbook told me the proof, but I can't understand the intuition.

### Reference

Note that this theorem is cited by "Semiparametric Theory and Missing Data" by Tsiatis Corollary3.1. I changed notation and the dimension of target parameter from $q$ to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This theorem is for the special case where the parameter $\theta$ can be partitioned as $(\beta,\eta)$.

First consider the setting where the estimator is the MLE.  The influence function of the MLE is $\phi=I^{-1}S$, so
$$E[\phi_\theta S_\theta^T]= E[I^{-1}_\theta S_\theta S_\theta^T]$$
and by the information identity this is just the identity matrix. Taking advantage of the decomposition of the parameter, $E[\phi_\beta S_\beta]$ is the identity and $E[\phi_\beta S_\eta^T]$ is zero. So for MLEs the result is just the information identity.

Now, suppose we have two estimators $\hat\theta_{MLE}$ and $\hat\theta_{other}$, that both have influence functions.  What is their covariance matrix?

We know the asymptotic variance for $\hat\beta_{MLE}$ is $I^{-1}_\beta$
and for $\hat\beta_{other}$ is it larger, so write $I^{-1}_\beta+\Delta$.  The interesting term is the asymptotic covariance.  We know that no linear combination of $\hat\beta_{MLE}$ and $\hat\beta_{other}$ can have smaller asymptotic variance than $\hat\beta_{MLE}$, because that's what efficiency means.  This implies the asymptotic covariance between $\hat\beta_{MLE}$ and $\hat\beta_{other}$ is also $I^{-1}_\beta$. Because uncorrelated implies independent for multivariate Normals,  asymptotically  $\hat\theta_{other}$ is $\hat\theta_{MLE}$ plus independent random noise. This is the Convolution Theorem; it's one of the asymptotic versions of the Cramér-Rao bound.

Everything else is just algebra.  Asymptotically
$$\mathrm{cov}[\hat\beta_{MLE},\hat\beta_{other}]=\mathrm{var}[\hat\beta_{MLE}].$$

If we premultiply both sides of this expression by the information $I_\beta$, we get the identity matrix on the right-hand side and on the left-hand side we get
$$\mathrm{cov}[S_\beta, \hat\beta_{other}]=1$$
and because the whole point of influence functions is that they linearise the estimator
$$\mathrm{cov}[S_\beta, \phi_{other}(\beta)]=1.$$
And there's a similar argument for the second equality.